# Error while connecting to AD via Java

Tags: java, active-directory

I'm trying to access AD via java.  When I run the code, I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 8009030C:
>   LdapErr: DSID-0C0903C5, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data
>   2030, v23f0 ] at com.ceiwc.TestAD.main(TestAD.java:40) Caused by:
>   javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 8009030C:
>   LdapErr: DSID-0C0903C5, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data
>   2030, v23f0 ] at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
>     at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
>     at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.naming.InitialContext.init(Unknown Source)  at
>   javax.naming.InitialContext.(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.ceiwc.TestAD.main(TestAD.java:38)

I am getting the same exact error as [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872617/ldap-error-while-connecting-to-ad-server).
Is anyone familiar with the error?

Here is my code:

```
String ldapAdServer = "ldap://ivdstest.testserver.com";
String userName = "lds";
String password = "Testing.";
Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<String, Object>();

env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userName);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapAdServer);

DirContext ctx;
    try {
      ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
     } catch (NamingException e) {
       throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you too lazy to search for error code 49?

Comment: No @Michael-O, I'm not lazy at all!  Are you that silly that that is all you could come up with?  Thanks for the lack of help!

Comment: No, you simply indicated that you do not understand the error.

Comment: For your clarification, I found error codes, but I was wondering what other parts of the message meant and if that information could be used to help me solve the problem.

Comment: Providea full UPN for the login, not simply a local username.